# Serving VisualSVN Server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am having hard time connecting to my VisualSVN Server repository from computers outside of my home network.

So far I only tried replacing my computer name with my computer's IP in the repository URL but this does not work;

```
https://MY-PC/svn/ProjectTrunk
```

Can you point me the steps I need to ensure I can serve the repository to outside computers?

Comment: This is more of a serverfault question.  If you can attach on the LAN, it could be your router or your ISP filtering out outbound HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to setup some dynamic DNS solution such as [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/), which allows you to access your computer using a fixed name (even if its IP address changes).

Answer (score 4):

Do you use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)? If not - DO, it will make your life a lot easier.

some other things:

1. use the IP address (don't use 192.x.x.x either, use the EXTERNAL IP, so you can get to it from outside), and NOT YOUR COMPUTER NAME for repo location
2. make sure the port is open on your router and firewall
3. make sure you specify the port number when you connect to your repo

To respond to your comment:

Right-click on your server (in the VisualSVN Server Manager), go to Properties and then click on Network tab - you'll see the port there. When you connect to your repo do this:

`https://111.111.111.111:8443/svn/PeojectTrunk`

(8443 is the port number, 111.111.111.111 is your IP)

Comment: I am using visualsvn server. How do you identify the port number?